# CanCan: Fetching records for a HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm using CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` to fetch Merchant instances which are accessible to `current_user`.  My data model is below:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :merchants
end
```

**app/models/merchant.rb**

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**app/models/ability.rb**

```
class Ability
 ....
 can [:read, :update], Merchant, users: { id: user.id }
end
```

**app/controllers/merchants_controller.rb**

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_load_resource only: [:create]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

The problem that I'm having is that the index action will load the appropriate merchant entites correctly. However, when the show action is performed (and attempts to authorize a single merchant, I get the following error:

`undefined method 'id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000007a23800>`

Does the CanCan rule I have defined for access to Merchants applicable to both listing a collection of merchants, and showing individual ones? Do I need a separate rule? I'm a little stumped here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the `cancancan` [gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) appears to have fixed my problem.  The last merge into the original cancan gem was Sept 2013, so I'm going to assume that this was just an unaddressed bug.

Comment: Hi am having the same issue even with cancancan, how did you resolve it?